# Please use meaningful copy for links

Tags: discussion

Please don't do things like this:

> There's a fairly good explanation [here](http://www.answering-islam.org/BibleCom/lk18_19.htm)

Here? Where? [That phrasing is poor and confusing](http://www.mardahl.dk/2010/11/22/i-dont-want-to-read-more-or-click-here/).

Here's a better phrasing:

> The [Answering Islam](http://www.answering-islam.org/BibleCom/lk18_19.htm) site gives a good explanatin.

What I'm saying is, everyone should read the article "[I don't want to read more or click here](http://www.mardahl.dk/2010/11/22/i-dont-want-to-read-more-or-click-here/)" and apply the lessons therein to their writing here and elsewhere on the Internet. It's a basic accessibility guideline.

Comment: [Click here](http://www.soloseo.com/blog/2007/05/29/learn-seo-basics-anchor-text/) for a site about SEO optimization.  I think it would be a much better source for your argument...

Comment: Please note that I removed the link to the answer with bad copy because the thing to do is edit it so that it reads correctly, in which case the link is going to be useless. Note that you have edit powers too ... although a post here constructively informing people about this issue is good too.

Comment: @Richard: SEO optimization?  I may have to report you to the Department of Redundancy Department for that...

Comment: Hehe.  ;)  I had the comment "[An SEO Optimization site] would be a better source...", but I couldn't resist the irony.

Answer (score 3):

@TRiG, your better phrashing is indeed better, but I believe your link text is still misplaced.  The anchor text ought to describe the link directly.  I propose:

> The Answering Islam site gives [a good explanation](http://www.answering-islam.org/BibleCom/lk18_19.htm).

Comment: It's pretty much a matter of taste. Also, I'd rather linkify "gives a good explanation".

Comment: Yeah, you're probably right.